# OpenModelica with Python

Tags: openmodelica

I created two models in OpenModelica-V1.12. One model has the main part and other model has the math related calculations. Main model uses the other model for the calculations. This works fine in OpenModelica.

When I launch the main model using Python with OMPython it shows the below error:

*Error: Error occurred while flattening model Sim_FS_SingleEx*.

How do I include the dependent models (.mo) in python?

Any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can send two expressions to omc:

```
loadFile("file1.mo"); 
loadFile("file2.mo");
```

Better still would be to make your models into a library, then you can just load Library/package.mo which will load all the files from the library automatically.

Comment: Hi Adiran,  Thank you very much for your reply. I am using Enhanced OMPython in Python to launch the model.

Comment: *from OMPython import ModelicaSystem*

Comment: *mod=ModelicaSystem("BouncingBall.mo","BouncingBall", "dependent.mo")*

Comment: When I use the above command in Python it is not able to identify the dependent.mo

Comment: The third parameter are libraries, not .mo files that's why is not working.

Comment: Seems is not possible to use ModelicaSystem and load several files. I will open a bug about it so we can fix it.

Comment: I opened a ticket about this:
https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/ticket/5289

Comment: Hi Adiran, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the ticket. You can specify .mo files in the third parameter.

Comment: Hi Adiran, Thank you very much